# Magento 1.9 Sass Fallback Structure

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme, sass, scss

I am trying to get the Sass fallbacks to work with Magento 1.9. I have created my own theme as skin/frontend/rwd/mytheme.

I have followed the instructions here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#sass-fallback-structure by using the following code in the rwd/default/scss/config.rb file:

```
add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"
```

To find the original Sass files. I have deleted all except layout/_footer.scss from my theme. When I try to compile with CodeKit I get this error:

[image]

Clearly it's not finding the fallbacks. I have also tried putting the add_import_path code into my theme's config.rb file and the root config.rb file but nothing seems to work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In step 2 of the "Sass Fallback Structure", it indicates specific directories that you are allowed to delete. However there are some files that you MUST have in your custompackage/customtheme/scss directory, and those are:

`var.scss
core.scss
styles-ie8.scss
styles.scss
scaffold-forms.scss
custom_core.scss
framework.scss`

If you have those files in your `scss` directory, you should be able to compile the Sass files using Codekit.

I don't have Codekit, but here is proof via the command line that this will work, if you set things up correctly:

[image]

Comment: Talk about straight from the Llama's mouth.

Comment: You are right - it seems the problem is with my Codekit/Sass/Compass versions all conflicting with each other.

Answer (score 2):

The path to the Ruby configuration file given in the tutorial seems odd to me.

Shouldn't we put this add_import_path at the custom theme level? i.e.

```
skin/frontend/custompackage/customtheme/scss/config.rb
```

Instead of

```
skin/frontend/rwd/default/config.rb
```

(Which does not even exist as it's in the scss subfolder)

One other thing: by following the instruction [Step 2: Copying Files For Your Theme](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#theme-copyfiles) we are also copying the config.rb. Shouldn't the http_path be updated as well?

## Edit: one example of config.rb in development environment

```
# note: this should never truly be refernced since we are using relative assets  
add_import_path "../../../rwd/default/scss"  
http_path = "/skin/frontend/custompackage/customtheme"  
css_dir = "../css"  
sass_dir = "../scss"  
images_dir = "../images"  
javascripts_dir = "../js"  
relative_assets = true  

output_style = :expanded  
environment = :development
```

Note: this works for me on different projects but my customtheme is always "default", i.e. *custompackage/default* (I see no reason why I souldn't work with any other name)

Comment: I'm with you on this.  But I think the import path does not change and should be added to the custom directory while http_path should change to the custom directory

Comment: I just tested this.  What I did was add a config.rb file to a theme in the RWD package, changed the http_path from "default" to my theme name, then added the add_import_path to this custom config file.  It works great with my compass watch.  I would assume, somewhere, I will need to tell the system to watch this scss directory along with the RWD, but I'm not there yet.

Comment: @tPlummer Nice to have you on my side. :)  My questions were rhetorical of course. Edited my answer with one config.rg of mine, hopefully it might help someone.

Comment: "Nothing goes over my head. My reflexes are too fast. I would catch it."  You wouldn't happen to know where Magento/RWD keeps the Compass compiler script by chance? Anything in RWD auto compiled, which is neat, but I want my custom overrides to join the party.

Comment: "I am Groot". Sorry but not sure what you mean. Doesn't the [Documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#theme-compass) say enough on this point?

Comment: I put this into a new question.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/45770/1-9ce-rwd-scss-auto-compiler

Comment: Also, `sourcemap = true` at the bottom of the rb to help a brother out