# 1.9CE RWD SCSS auto-compiler

Tags: rwd

So, I've been through the [documentation](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide#theme-compass) on setting up the override structure for SCSS files--which is VERY impressive by the way.  I can manually compile/watch them via terminal/CL just fine.  BUT, what I've noticed is that somewhere, buried, Magento or RWD has a script that is watching the default SCSS folder in RWD and will compile it automatically whenever it sees a change.  BUT, obviously, it doesn't know that my new skin exists and thus does not compile the custom skin.

I've looked through my repo and other source docs and can't find anything about it.

Would anyone know if this is a thing or if something on my host is set to do this?  I wouldn't think SASS files would compile themselves...unless they've become sentient.  But I never considered myself good enough to accidentally write up a Compass-AI.

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support in magento to compile scss files. You need to use a tool like [scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/), [koala](http://koala-app.com/), [compass](http://compass-style.org/) or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) or something. There are several tool out there to compile scss files.

Another option is to implemnt a php based compiler like [leafo/scssphp](http://leafo.net/scssphp/).

cheers